# Gradient boosting understanding of residual picture

Tags: gradient-descent, boosting, ensemble-learning

I recently looking at the Gradient boosting using following blog

https://medium.com/mlreview/gradient-boosting-from-scratch-1e317ae4587d

I try to understand the picture but I need some help

[image]

For my understanding of Gradient Boosting. 
$e1 = y- y_{predicted}$  (this is right residual right)?
and then $e1_{predicted}$has to be added with $y_{predicted1}$(which is red_line).

$y_{predicted2} = y_{predicted1}+ e1_{predicted}$
is this going to be prediction(iteration2)??

but How they get the second red line from adding first redline + residual prediction?

Answer (score 0):

I think that both $y_{predicted1}$ and $e1_{predicted}$ are output values from base regressor (decision tree) $T_0$ fitted on $\{(x_i, y_i)\}_{i=1}^N$ ($N$ is the size of the dataset) and $T_1$ fitted on $\{(x_i, y_i - T_0(x_i))\}$.

Generalising the training process you train the $i$-th regressor of the ensemble on dataset $\{(x_i, y_i - \sum_{k=0}^{i-1}T_k(x_i))\}$.

The final regressor $f_M(x)$ - an ensemble of M trees, assuming you stop training after M steps because the residual error falls below some small threshold - is $f_M(x) = \sum_{k=0}^{M - 1}T_k(x))$.

You can get the $i$-th red line just by plotting $f_i(x)$ (summing the predictions of the first $i$ base regressors).